# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ab:games'. One of '{"http://teste2.org":player}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd

Can you guys help me understand this error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ab:games'.
>   One of '{"http://teste2.org":player}' is expected.

Why is player expected inside games? Player is expected in goals at most given accord with my schema.

I'm using `XSDValidator.java`

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ab:nationalTeam xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                                   
                 xmlns:ab="http://teste2.org"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://teste2.org PT.xsd">
<ab:player id="1">
    <ab:number>1</ab:number>
    <ab:name>Eduardo</ab:name>
</ab:player>
<ab:player id="11">
    <ab:number>11</ab:number>
    <ab:name>Eder</ab:name>
</ab:player>
<ab:player id="2">
    <ab:number>10</ab:number>
    <ab:name>Vieirinha</ab:name>
</ab:player>
<ab:games>
 <ab:game>
    <ab:adversary>
        France
    </ab:adversary>
    <ab:goals >
        <ab:player id="11" minute="109"/>
    </ab:goals>
 </ab:game>
 </ab:games>
</ab:nationalTeam>
```

My schema:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:ab="http://teste2.org"
            targetNamespace="http://teste2.org"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

       <xs:complexType name="gameType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="adversary" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="goals" type="ab:goalsType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:complexType name="goalsType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ab:player"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:element name="games">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="game" type="ab:gameType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>   
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="player">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="number" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
             </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                  <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="minute" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="nationalTeam">
            <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ab:player" minOccurs="22" maxOccurs="25"/>
                    <xs:element ref="ab:games"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:key name="pk_id">
              <xs:selector xpath="ab:nationalTeam/ab:player"/>
              <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
            </xs:key>
            <xs:keyref name="fk_id" refer="ab:pk_id">
              <xs:selector xpath="ab:nationalTeam/ab:games/ab:game/ab:goals/ab:player"/>
              <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
            </xs:keyref>
        </xs:element>   

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSD clearly says that a `nationalTeam` must have between 22 and 25 players, followed by exactly 1 `games` element.

Your XML file only has 3 players.

Comment: Well that was anti-climatic. Now I feel silly for asking this. Thank you and I'm sorry for this mistake of mine.